# Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() after PHP 8.1.14 update

Tags: php, php-8.1, ssh2

After updating PHP 8.1 on Jan 7 2023 we began seeing "Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()" in previously working scripts.  The Jan 5 PHP release [changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php) does not mention SSH at all.  Apache2 has been manually restarted and eventually a full reboot was done.

We are running PHP 8.1.14 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2023 08:34:41) (NTS) under Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

In phpinfo() output I see libSSH Version libssh2/1.8.0 with /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini as primary ini loaded. There is not however any SSH extension explicitly enabled in that file and phpinfo() only lists libSSH and no larger SSH config table is shown.

Additional INI files parsed do not reference SSH in their names

```
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-bz2.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-intl.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-soap.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

Issuing sudo apt install php-ssh2 gets
php-ssh2 is already the newest version (1.3.1+0.13-7+0~20221209.25+debian10~1.gbp33475c).

Additionally `sudo apt remove php-ssh2` and `sudo apt install php-ssh2` were issued along with `sudo service apache2 restart` but this did not change the " Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()" error.

Do I need to add a line explicitly enabling ssh2 in the primary ini? How best to further chase the error?

Comment: Try `apt install php8.1-ssh2`

Comment: And `service php8.1-fpm reload` if you're using fpm.

Comment: Isn't that a PECL extension?

Comment: @Marwelln please add answer so I can accept and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how installing php specific modules work without specifying a version number, but to be sure you get the module you want for your specific PHP-version add the version after `php`. In your case it would be `php8.1`

So to install ssh2 for PHP 8.1 with `apt` you would use `apt install php8.1-ssh2`.

*If you're using FPM running PHP you need to make sure you reload it after installing a new module (`service php8.1-fpm reload`).*